# Disclosure (13D, insiders) and equity swaps/options

Tags: united-states, options

What is the current SEC ruling on equity swaps and options?

For example, 13D requires that When a person or group of persons acquires beneficial ownership of more than 5% of a voting class of a company’s equity securities,

Yet when I buy options, I don't have any voting class nor any of the company's equity. Same for equity swaps.

Will  the SEC disclosure rules 13D + 3,4,5 still apply in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Holding exchange traded options won't trigger any SEC disclosure rules.

Being granted a large options position as an agent of the company creates voluntary disclosure rules on the form 3, 4. Exercising those options is a mandatory disclosure and gifting the options/shares is also mandatory.

A large buy or sell is a 13D disclosure.

Comment: acutally since 2002 they have

Comment: @pound2strong really? I wasn't aware of that can you show me an example, or the regulation?